# React Router v6 - Direct links to a subpage return a 404 error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

For my wedding, I've created a small React app to provide guidance to the guests: https://louis-et-marianne.com/

Accessing my 2nd page https://louis-et-marianne.com/dormir only works from the homepage, but I get a 404 when accessing this page URL directly.

Any ideas?

Here is my App.js code where the routes are defined:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Wrapper>
        <ThemeProvider theme={customTheme}>
          <CssBaseline enableColorScheme />
          <Link to="/" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
            <Hero />
          </Link>
          <Container maxWidth="md">
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<Accueil />} />
              <Route path="/dormir" element={<Dormir />} />
              <Route path="*" element={<h1>Page not found.</h1>} />
            </Routes>
            <Box
              display="flex"
              alignItems="center"
              justifyContent="center"
              mt={6} mb={6}
              sx={{ transform: "rotate(13deg)" }}
            >
              <img src={betise} alt="Bétise de Cambray" width="100px" />
            </Box>
          </Container>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </Wrapper>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And here is the full project on Github: https://github.com/byloupom/l-et-m

Thanks!

Comment: Review the [cra deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) to see if there's a relevant section for your server environment and follow those steps for configuring your server. The gist is that the server should be configured to redirect page requests for "nested" pages to the root index.html file so the React app loads and can handle the routing/navigation internally.

Answer (score 0):

its not a react js issue it has to do with the hosting provider not redirecting all the requests to the index.html file if this is hosted on github pages i dont think it supports this.

you can read it here https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/408